# Free (or OS) cloud backup program

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, cloud, jungledisk, application

I am looking for program which would allow me to backup data from Windows web server 2008 to cloud storage (Amazon, Rackspace and so on) - sites and mssql express backup files and automatically encrypt these files.

If what I know is correct that this functionality provides Jungle Disc or CloudBerry Backup Server or Zmanda Cloud Backup which are all commercial programs. I am looking for something open-source or at least free runing under .NET (or native application for windows) - no Java or something like this.

Does it exist?

Yes and of course: It would be nice if it was possible to decrypt backup on home computer.

EDIT:

I have found software on http://www.secobackup.com/downloads3.html which support Amazon S3 storage.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.maluke.com/software/s3-backup

Comment: By their website it is not free but it costs 75 USD (you have 60 days trial). In this light Cloudberry seems better.

Answer (score 2):

Most cloud storage providers either provide their own software/API or they use standard network/file transfer protocols to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: That is true, I can combine several programs to make it work but - for me - better solution is one-package-program. By the way, there is tutorial for something similar on http://codeblog.theg2.net/2010/02/powershell-7-zip-amazon-s3-upload.html

Answer (score 1):

You mention Zamanda as a commercial product, they also have an open source/community version available:

http://amanda.zmanda.com/

here's the feature comparison for community vs enterprise:

http://www.zmanda.com/Amanda-Enterprise-Amanda-Community-comparison.html

Comment: Well yes, Zmanda offers community edition but it has server/client architecture (I do not know if server can backup itself or if it needs client software, but it is not importand) however if you want to backup to cloud storage you need to buy a licence by http://www.zmanda.com/pricing.html

Comment: @Walium: You can backup to an Amazon S3 with Amanda without buying commercial license. Their wiki explains how to set it up manually.

Comment: @Walium - that's only if you want to use their cloud storage solution.  Since you already have your own fancy "cloud" storage, then just point your backup software to that and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Areca Backup](http://www.areca-backup.org/).
It can't directly store anything on S3, but it can connect to SSH (SFTP).
I have an EC2 instance running Ubuntu with an OpenSSH server and the [S3QL](http://code.google.com/p/s3ql/) driver to mount an S3 bucket.

Areca Backup is written in Java, has encryption, incremental backups and compression.
S3QL also has encryption and compression.

It's probably not the kind of tool you were looking for (since it needs a linux server between your machine and the S3 bucket) but it gets the job done and is cheaper than paying for a commercial solution.